# Android Screen Brightness Lock

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, brightness

I am creating an android application that needs to keep the device awake (will not lock) like this:

[image]

please help me to add the "Screen light lock" **check-box** in my settings activity. (in java, adt bundle eclipse)

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

in your activity :

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.wakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK |     
PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "My Tag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you meant, you need to keep the device awake (will not lock), 
At the onCreate use this line of code:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

for knowing better see this: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html